# how to get the following font to look right

Tags: css

I have the following fonts and there are some gaps between certain words. I guess I could play around with the fonts and width but just would like to know if is it usually the fonts or the width that is causing the problem? I thought that it could be the font issue being too big.... but am confused here

```
div.service1 {
  width: 19em;
  border: 1px solid #8B4513;
  margin: 1em 5em;
  padding: 0 .3em;
  float: left;


}

div.service1 p{
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #000000;
  width: 8em;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin: 1.25em;

}

div.services {
  width: 180em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 340em;
  left: 8em;
}

div.service1 h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div.services #piano {
   font-size: 30px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   text-align: center

}

div.services #violin {
   font-size: 30px;
   margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.services #sax {
   font-size: 30px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   text-align: center;
}

div.services h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #8B4513;
  color:#000000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 -6px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

div.services_heading {
   font-size: 5em;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: 'Aldrich', sans-serif;
   font-family: 'Mr Dafoe', cursive ;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 65em;
   left: 8.5em;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which style is being assigned to which paragraph here?

Comment: I think it could that the width is too small

Comment: the service1 p is for the wording and the best width I could give is 10 width

Comment: I think that width 8 or 9 is better

Comment: I guess it is all about finding the balance between the width and font

Comment: More like the width and the number of words you have to show

Answer (score -2):

It's probarbly the `text-align: justify;` that's causing you problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify

Comment: thanks but I like the text align: justify; property.. I guess I will have to make do with this setting